# How to maximise the sum of three unknowns in a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm trying to solve the kind of linear equation below such that the sum of the unknowns is maximised, but have been unable to find the solution.

$$\frac{10}{y_1}+\frac{12}{y_2}+\frac{15}{y_3}=50$$

It may just be I am searching using the wrong terminology, if so direction of where to look would be greatly appreciated too.

EDIT:
To add some more information, the initial problem involved four equations.

$$y_1=K_1/x_1$$

$$y_2=K_2/x_2$$

$$y_3=K_3/x_3$$

$$x_1+x_2+x_3=X$$

Where K and X values are given constants, and x and y values are unknown. I am trying to find a solution that maximises the sum of the y values.

It is from this problem that I simplified it to

$$\frac{K_1}{y_1}+\frac{K_2}{y_2}+\frac{K_3}{y_3}=X$$

With the first equation in the initial question just being arbitrary values.

Comment: More information is needed, as $(y_1,y_2,y_3)=\left(10^n,12,\frac {15}{49-10^{-(n-1)}}\right) $ is always a solution and these have arbitrarily large sum.

Comment: I'm trying to produce a generic solution to the problem $$\frac{K_1}{y_1}+\frac{K_2}{y_2}+\frac{K_3}{y_3}=X$$ where the K values and X are given constants, with this problem derived from a more complex problem

Comment: I don't know what "generic" means in this context.  And I don't know what this might have to do with the optimization problem you actually posed.

Comment: Apologies, I have added more information to the initial question - thanks for your guidance so far

Comment: No problem, but look at my first comment.  You can take $y_1$ to be gigantic, and still find positive $y_2,y_3$ that satisfy the equation.  Therefore there is no maximum.  There ought to be a minimum, of course.

Comment: Note:  I'm assuming all variables are positive, though you did not specify this.  If negative values are allowed then there isn't a minimum either.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, thank you very much - it seems I got my wires crossed with the very initial problem hence was searching for a maximum but one does not exist. You did assume correctly that all variables are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal appears to be to maximize the function $f(x)=y_1+y_2+y_3$ with the constraint that $\frac{10}{y_1}+\frac{12}{y_2}+\frac{15}{y_3}=50$.
This can be solved with Legrange multipliers. In case you haven't heard of this, the idea is that the for any critical point of a function $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ constrained by the equation $g(x)=K$ where $K$ is a constant, there exists a value of $\lambda$ where

$f_{x_1}=\lambda g_{x_1}$; $f_{x_2}=\lambda g_{x_2}$; $f_{x_3}=\lambda g_{x_3}$; $\cdots$

We can use this to solve your optimization problem by creating this system of equations:

$1=-\lambda\frac{10}{y_1^2}$;
$1=-\lambda\frac{12}{y_2^2}$;
$1=-\lambda\frac{15}{y_3^2}$

which simplifies to $-\lambda=\frac{y_1^2}{10}=\frac{y_2^2}{12}=\frac{y_3^2}{15}$ or $-60\lambda=6y_1^2=5y_2^2=4y_3^2$.
You can substitute this is to the original constraint to get $2.5y_1^2=50$ and $y_1=\sqrt{10}$. Therefore, $\lambda=-1$. This means that the solution is $(\sqrt{10}, 2\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{15})$